# Bitwise operations, how to check for 0 or 1?

Tags: java

I have an integer like:

```
0x10000010
```

I would like to know if a particular bit is 1 or 0. For example, something like:

```
int number = 0x10000010;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (ith bit == 1) {
        System.out.println("bit " + i + " is 1.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("bit " + i + " is 0.");
    }
}

---- output ----
bit 0 is 1
bit 1 is 0
bit 2 is 0
bit 3 is 0
bit 4 is 0
bit 5 is 0
bit 6 is 1
bit 7 is 0
```

I've forgotten how to do this, and what this type of operation is called,

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`number & (1 << i)` will be 0 if the bit wasn't set, non-zero if it was.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to dty's answer

```
int number = 0b10000010; // you are assuming this is binary not hex.
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if((number >> i) & 1 != 0)
        System.out.println("bit " + i + " is 1.");
     else 
        System.out.println("bit " + i + " is 0.");
}
```

or

```
int number = 0b10000010; // you are assuming this is binary not hex.
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
    System.out.println("bit " + i + " is " + ((number >> i) & 1));
```

Comment: I can't get that number definition to compile, "0b10000000" - is the "b" syntax supposed to compile ok? Thanks

Comment: Binary literals were added in Java 7. You can use `Integer.parseInt("10000010", 2);`